# MYSQL - foreign key varchar column

Tags: mysql

I would like to add localization to my database. I created `languages` table and I would like to add foreign key to user table:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `registrationDate` datetime DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `lastLoginDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `isConfirmed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `activationKey` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `resendEmail` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `subscribedNews` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `activated` tinyint(1) DEFAULT 1,
  `lang` varchar(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'en'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


ALTER TABLE `users`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`);

ALTER TABLE `users`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

create table languages(
    code varchar(5) primary key,
    name varchar(255) not null,
    dateFormat varchar(255),
    dateTimeFormat varchar(255),
    currency varchar(255)
);

ALTER TABLE users
ADD lang varchar(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'cs';

ALTER TABLE users ADD CONSTRAINT fk_user_lang FOREIGN KEY (lang) REFERENCES languages(code);
```

I can't add foreign key on `lang` column:

> error code: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"

Why I can't create varchar foreign key. I would not add int primary key in languages table, because, I would like to get data from database as `/api/users/cs` instead of `/api/users?lang=1`.

Thanks

Comment: both datatypes for FK columns are needed to be same

Comment: Your code works in this db fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=73f21d409681d3695f18dd77598f0d59. Likely, you are not runnning the exact same code in your database.

Comment: what does `select version()` give?

Comment: @ysth 10.4.11-MariaDB. Can it depend on the mysql server settings?

Comment: @bluray just grasping at straws, since no one else seems to be able to get your error.  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=f6481b618afee2b491c606bebdd01782
  please show output of `show create table users` before doing the alter tables?

Comment: @ysth I added my latest version of users table with `alter table add lang`.

Comment: what does `select @@storage_engine;` show?

Comment: @ysth It show "InnoDb"

Comment: @bluray is there a reason that you did not accept my answer which was posted earlier and provided the code to solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify the character set or collation for the `languages` table.

Whereas `users` is explicitly `utf8`, you might be using a MySQL version where the default charset is utf8mb4 or a very old version where the default charset is latin1.

Double-check with:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE languages\G
```

That will display the charset and collation for that table. It must be the same as the charset and collation for the foreign key column in `users`.

Comment: Problem was in different collations

Answer (score 0):

If you change the default character set of the table `languages` to `utf8`, which you defined for the table `users`, then it will work:

```
ALTER TABLE languages CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=39f83ea12886dbde13aaa42304b51cb3).